# How to append array to associative array in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array declared outside of a foreach loop which I use to add value to the array. Right now, its overwriting values in the array during each loop. The goal is to not overwrite but append value to the array so when the foreach loop is finished, I will have the complete values instead of values from the last loop. Here is the example

```
$vars = array(
            'year' => null,
            'make' => null,
            'model' => null
        );

foreach (){

   $year = array(
     '2000',
     '2001',
     '2002'
  );

 $make = array('honda'); // only 1 value
 $model =  array('accord'); // only 1 value

 // do something here to append $year, $make, $model to the correct key in $vars

}
```

so the result should look like this

```
 $vars = array 
 (
                 'year' => array('2000','2001','2002,'2003','2004','2005','2006'),
                 'make' => array('honda','toyota','nissan'),
                 'model' => array('accord','camery','altima')
 )
```

maybe somewhere in foreach to check and avoid inserting duplicate values would be nice. e.g.. no duplicate years, make and models.

Comment: Try append_toyota and append_nissan ;)
Please adjust your question

Comment: There is pretty much no reason to set those values as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with -

```
$vars['year'] = array_merge($var['year'], $year);
```

Same with `make` & `model`.

Comment: And to avoid duplicate values, check array_unique method => http://php.net/array_unique

Comment: `array_unique` will help if it contains duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 foreach (){

     $year = array('2000','2001','2002');

     $make = array('honda');
     $model =  array('accord'); 

     array_push($vars['year'],$year);
     array_push($vars['make'],$make);
     array_push($vars['model'],$model);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not have a common parameter to insert all the parameters in one foreach() loop.try more loops like this

```
$vars = array(
'year' => null,
'make' => null,
'model' => null
);
$year = array(
'2000',
'2001',
'2002'
);
$make = array('honda'); // only 1 value
$model = array('accord'); // only 1 value

foreach ($year as $years) {
$vars['year'][] = $years;
}
foreach ($make as $makes) {
$vars['make'][] = $makes;
}
foreach ($model as $models) {
$vars['model'][] = $models;
}
```